# Characters at a certain horizontal position have "fat", "fuzzy" vertical strokes

Tags: linux, display, fonts

I'm on Gnome 44.1, Arch Linux, haven't touched anything related to fonts since I've installed the system, and sometimes parts of the characters appear too fat, with "smearings"... the characters in question always have the same horizontal position. When a character is problematic, the ones above and below it will be as well, provided they have a stroke that lines up with the problematic vertical line.

Sadly I cannot capture it on a screenshot because it depends on the exact position of the character on the screen. To give you an idea, it's almost as if the letter looked like the style used to represent number sets, with a double stroke.

I'm using an ultra wide monitor, don't know if that has to do with that... it's a Philips 346B1C.

edit: took a photo of the screen: [image: in the red circle, the problematic letter; in the green ones, the same letter rendered fine]